# Create intPtr to matrix

Tags: c#, pointers, intptr

I'm using a struct for to return values ​​from a C dll, my struct in C#:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct board
    {
        public IntPtr boardMatrix;  //representacion matricial del tablero
        public int size;  //tamaño del tablero
        public int id;
    }
```

and i need make a pointer to `int[,] matrix` for unmanaged memory

to define this assignment:

```
int[,] myMatrix;
board boardExample = new board();
boardExample.boardMatrix = myMatrix // intPtr <= [,]int
```

How you could do this conversion ?